# How to save a translation of a plugin in "CodeStyling Localization"?

Tags: translation

Hi I was translating one of my plugins in "CodeStyling Localization". when I update my plugin my translation erased. Is there anyway to find it ? And How can I backup my translation (I don't want to waste my time next time :))

Comment: If you don't have a backup of your translation, yes, unfortunately you lost it. And if you don't have any, use this plugin ([BackWpUp](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/)) or similar together with DropBox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should move the po- and mo-file with the translation of your plugin outside your plugin's directory. Whenever you update your plugin, your plugin files are replaced causing any file that is not part of the default plugin package to be deleted. (If you are translating your own plugin, you could as well add the translation files directly to your plugin repository.)

How to move custom translation files outside of the plugin's directory? In your plugin code, add a method like this to the `init` hook:

```
public function load_plugin_textdomain()
{
    $domain = 'my-plugin';
    $locale = apply_filters('plugin_locale', get_locale(), $domain);

    load_textdomain($domain, WP_LANG_DIR.'/my-plugin/'.$domain.'-'.$locale.'.mo');
    load_plugin_textdomain($domain, FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/');
}
```

The code above first looks for a translation file in `WP_LANG_DIR`, to be found in `wp-content/languages/` by default. Putting your custom translation files in there is safe for upgrades.

Also, by using the the approriate hook and functions to load the translations for your plugin, you allow users to hook into the language loading process for your plugin, giving them much flexibility to load language file(s) from anywhere they want.

I've written [a more in-depth article](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/article/loading-wordpress-language-files-the-right-way) about this on my blog.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Geert . I translate other plugins with poedit and I upload them manually and I have no problems yet . Is it for some of the plugins ?

Comment: All I can say is that if you put your own translation files for a plugin in that plugin's directory, you lose them when upgrading the plugin.

Comment: Wonderful code, Geert, much appreciated! ps: the article too

Comment: You suggest here and also in your blog to use effectively `wp-content/languages/[my-plugin]` as the "update safe" directory. However if say you use the Loco plugin and WooCommerce itself puts the translations into `wp-content/languages/plugins` has this changed?

Comment: This has indeed changed in later wordpress versions. Now you use `wp-content/languages/plugins`. See also [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/533ddkx)