# Plugin translations files outside plugin directory?

Tags: plugins, translation, localization

I'm using the excellent Codestyling Localization plugin to translate themes and plugins.

But there's a problem when translating plugins, namely that the translated strings are saved to `wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/languages/gravityforms-LANG-CODE.*` for example.

This resulting in overwritten translations for subsequent plugin upgrades.

Is it possible to move the language files to another location? For example wp-content/languages or something else?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52407/22534), the article Geert linked is absolutely recommendable too. General information about translations/internationalization can be found in the wordpress codex: [Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress), [I18n for WordPress Developers](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). More specific information, in conjunction with the linked answer/article, can be found here: [load_plugin_textdomain()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain).

Comment: Ok, but I assumet that this requires that the plugin is coded "properly"/according to the article by @Geert.